# Using apply to run a function on multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to collect summary statistics on a number of variables (columns) after they have been grouped by a categorical variable. Instead of writing the code out individually for each variable I was hoping to use the `apply` function.

Here is the function I want to use without any apply added to it:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(my_data, group) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    mean = mean(weight, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(weight, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

I know this is a pretty rookie question, but I'm struggling to work it out using various apply tutorials. I think I'm finding it tricky because of the pipe.

Cheers!

Comment: See `summarise_at` and `summarise_all`

Comment: That worked great thanks!

As an additional question, I'd now like to run an ANOVA on each variable across the aforementioned groups without having to re-do the code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$car_brand), function(x){

        data.frame(

        car_brand = x$car_brand,

        counter = nrow(x),

        avg = mean(x$hp, na.rm = T),

        std_dev = ifelse(is.na(sd(x$hp, na.rm = T)), 0, sd(x$hp, na.rm = T)))

      }

    )

  ),

row.names = NULL

)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(car_type = row.names(mtcars), 
                 car_brand = gsub(" .*", "", row.names(mtcars)),
                 mtcars, row.names = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

functions based on *formula* e.g `lm`, `aov` etc have a problem with `group_by`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2177), therefore, here is one way using `purrr::map_*` and `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nms <- c('wt','qsec')
#loop over nms and apply the 2nd part, so .x will take 'wt' then `qsec` 
map_dfc(nms, 
        ~mtcars %>% 
          group_split(cyl) %>% 
          map_df(function(y) y %>%
                   summarise(!!quo_name(paste0("mean_",.x)):=mean(y[[.x]]),
                             !!quo_name(paste0("pval_",.x)):=summary(aov(as.formula(paste(.x,"~am")), data=y))[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[1]
                              )
                  )
        )

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  mean_wt pval_wt mean_qsec pval_qsec
    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1    2.29 0.0104       19.1  0.0166  
2    3.12 0.00101      18.0  0.00514 
3    4.00 0.218        16.8  0.000834
```